# Pytorch lightning "hp/metrics" does not work, as developers claim

Tags: tensorboard, python-logging, hyperparameters, pytorch-lightning

Lightning.pytorch offers a key `hp_metric` for logging user-defined metrics (i.e.cost function) to the *tensorboard/hparams* section. With this key, the user can sample experiments that have the metrics(cost) above/below some threshold value set in a special box:
[box:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUco3.jpg)

However, if you need to record multiple metrics, you have to specify your keys, and Lightning offers [instructions](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/logging.html?highlight=hp_metric#logging-hyperparameters) on how to do this. I followed these instructions, but nothing works.

I am really puzzled, I did everything in accordance to the lightning template, but it just does not work. In the tensorboard/hparams section I've got [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymbeJ.jpg)

Why it does not work? Here is my script.

```
import torch
import lightning.pytorch as pl
from train import do_training, Lit_train

from lightning.pytorch.loggers import TensorBoardLogger

def main(cfg: DictConfig):
        .......
    tb_logger = TensorBoardLogger("tb_logs", name="Experiment", default_hp_metric=False)
    tb_logger.log_hyperparams(cfg)

    model = Lit_train(model, .....,)

    trainer = pl.Trainer( .....,logger=tb_logger)
    trainer.fit(  model, train_loader, valid_loader)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()

class Lit_train(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self, model,.....):

        .....
    def on_train_start(self):
        self.logger.log_hyperparams(self.hparams, {"hp/metric_1": 0, "hp/metric_2": 0})

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        c, targets = batch
        rollout = self.model(c)
        loss = loss_fun(rollout, targets)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        c, targets = batch
        rollout = self.model(c)
        loss = loss_fun(rollout, targets)
        self.log("hp/metric_1",loss )
        self.log("hp/metric_2",loss )
```